# Can't get $_GET variables from mod_rewritten URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite a URL in PHP from `example.com/homehub/whatweneed.php?sort=default` to `example.com/homehub/whatweneed/sort/default`.

I've got the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sort/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ ^whatweneed.php?sort=$1 [QSA,PT,L]
```

It's rewriting the URL to what I want but I can't seem to get any of the variables passed through via $_GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

or

```
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']
```

Comment: And then just process the resulting string for what I want?

Comment: That should do it. Explode the above with the '/' symbol for an array of your variables.